# Proving a Certain Set Contains a Neighbourhood of 0 Using Multivariable Calculus

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I got stuck on a question midst my calculus course - quite a simple one to be honest. I don't
think any of the other students has gotten stuck on it (certainly not as much as myself), which leads me to believe it may be trivial. I think I just don't understand it really.
The question is phrased thus:

> Prove the set $\{A^2 + A | A \in M_{k \times k}(\mathbb{R})\}$ contians a neighborhood of $0$

Now, my professor noted that the basic idea is to choose a function
$f: M_{k \times k}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow  M_{k \times k}(\mathbb{R})$ (not entirely sure about the output, he didn't specify that part) such that it is differentiable at $A$, as in:
\begin{gather*}
    \frac{|f(A + H) - f(A) - Df_A(H)|}{|H|} \xrightarrow[H \rightarrow O_{k \times k}]{} 0
\end{gather*}

I guess I should choose an $f$ such that the numerator in the above limit
will approach $|A^2 + A|$ when $H$ approaches $O$. However I am not entirely sure
what to look for, or how exactly this would work.

I am a bit confused about how functions that take matrix and return matrix work in terms of differential calculus...

What would $Df$ mean in that case?
How does one find a term for $Df$ at a point $A$?
How should one  calculate such a limit as presented above?
Also, I assume (according to my text book and my professor) that $|H|$ means the length of the vector with $k^2$ elements that is a concatenation $H$'s rows. Why does that represent a "length" of a matrix?
In addition, this assignment should test our knowledge about the process of locating extrema points, second derivatives, tangent spaces and smooth manifolds, I truly don't see the connection here to any of these subjects.

I have not yet developed an intuitive understanding of functions from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}$, all the more so when speaking about matrices.
Thus, I would be glad to receive some references or examples that could help me understand such functions better.

Any help or comment would be extremely and greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much and have a great morning, evening or night!

Comment: $Df$ is the derivative matrix (the equivalent of the derivative for multivariate calculus). If you are not sure what $Df$ is, I don't really think you have a chance at solving this question unless you go back and read/watch through whatever material you are learning from. We can help you with a problem, but this seems like you have a hole in your understanding.

Comment: @DonThousand Hi, and thank you for the comment! I understand what $Df$ represents in general, and I know what does a *jacobian matrix* mean, but I don't understand what exactly it means here in this context, with this "matrix" function. Should I regard this square matrices space as a normal euclidean space? (as in $\mathbb{R}^l$)

Comment: Any matrix space can be viewed as a vector space. For the set of all matrices of dimension $n\times m$, the dimension of that vector space (which is also a euclidean space) is $nm$. Perhaps you would be a bit less confused if you unwrapped the matrix into a long vector?

Comment: Yes, you can think of $\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ as $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a path to understand the links between the elements where I denote $M_{k \times k}(\mathbb R)$ by $M$ to lighten the notations.

- $S(A)=\{A^2+A \mid A \in M\}$ is the image under the map $f: A^2+A$ of $M$. Also $f(0)=0$.
- If a map $g : M \to M$ is continuous with $g(0)=0$ then the inverse image of a neighborhood of $0$ is a neighborhood of zero by definition of continuity.
- If a continuously differentiable map $h$ between two normed linear spaces is such that $Df(0)$ is invertible, then $h$ is a local diffeomorphism according to inverse function theorem.

Now, you need to apply that to $f$. $f$ is a polynomial map (of matrices) and is therefore smooth (indefinitely differentiable). $Df(0)$ is the identity, which is invertible. Hence $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Hence it exists a local neighborhood of zero that is mapped to a neighborhood of zero. Which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: Actually makes a lot of sense this question is mostly about the inverse function theorem. In that case, I feel like the supposed hint my professor gave is a little bit misleading... Not sure what to make of it.